# What's the best server to use with ASP.Net on Mono?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mono, arch-linux

I am reconfiguring my website from scratch and basically I want it to run Mono(well, ASP.Net inside Mono)

According to the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET) there appears to be two options, Apache or Nginx.

Which one would be best for me? I'm running on Arch Linux x86-64, so I have packages for both. And I don't plan on (at least not in the immediate future) running any other software such as PHP. The only thing that must be supported is multiple-hosts support, for instance foo.com goes to Website A, and bar.com goes to Website B.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Apache with mod_mono since fastcgi-mono-server2 for nginx is probably still causing [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)). There are also some opened bugs (about memory leaks if I remember correctly) regarding mono fastcgi server and it's suggested to use Apache rather than nginx.

**EDIT:**

Thrashing: I tested it myself with old 2.4 release if I remember correctly (not sure if newer versions suffer from the same issue). [Here](http://psantos-blog.zi-yu.com/?p=298) is an article which mentions it.

> Other problem we had was the mono web process and the resources it used. Going to 600-900Mb RAM and wasting a lot of CPU, even at idle time.

[These](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=618043) [two](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=648900) bugs are about possible memory leaks when using fastcgi-mono-server.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference somewhere to back this up? I did http://www.google.com/search?q=mono+asp.net+nginx+thrashing and couldn't find anything

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu server 11.10 (ref [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/276422/best-way-to-setup-multi-user-environment-for-hosting-mono-asp-net/331050#331050) and [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/118256/asp-net-mono-performance-on-linux/335371#335371)) and recommend it.

Why? Default repo's are updated frequently for all that you the to host mono based websites (Apache, Lighttp or nginx). nginx is my choice. It's a easy to maintain distro.