# How to install mono in Linux server?

Tags: asp.net, linux, unix

I would like to install mono in Linux server.I don't know Linux.I have to work in .net application which will run in Linux server.I would also like to know how can i run my first asp.net application in linux server.Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Linux distribution?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/q/225604/2781

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, Mono can be installed from the repositories by installing the `mono-complete` package. Other distributions should also have packages in their repositories. Using the distribution's package manager is the preferred method of installation.

To do the install in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Here are instructions for [Debian](http://mono-project.com/DistroPackages/Debian).

See [this page](http://mono-project.com/Obtaining_Mono) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

In a yum/rpm based distro (Fedora), use

> yum install mono-complete