# Best way to setup multi user environment for hosting Mono ASP.NET

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, asp.net, ftp, mono

I'am thinking now a few day's about whats the best way is to give many users access via FTP to my server to upload there ASP.NET apps and execute it safetly.

I think I will use ProFTPD with mod-mysql and "CreateHome on" so I can manage all the user logins easily in a database and the user folders would create automaticly for me on first login.

My main problem is this:
How can I make that the ASP.NET app can't go outside of the FTP user home dir?
I readed that in the PHP world this problem could be solved with suEXEC when using the Apache2 webserver.

Can I do the same when using the fastcgi-mono-server?

Or is there any better solution with other webserver like NGINX or lighttpd?

Any tips how can I do this project at best and easiest?

Comment: Does realy no one have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can, I've did.

I have nginx with php-fpm ([some instructions](http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2011/01/installing-nginx-with-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-10-04/)), fastcgi-mono-server and perl/cgi. Then I have [pure-ftpd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PureFTP) (instructions, not using GUI) and I can create ftp accounts (1+) for each site root. I have a script for this but others have more complete ones that use db to store users settings more easy.

Sites structure:

```
/srv/www/www.mysite.com/public_html # actual site root and ftp root
/srv/www/www.mysite.com/logs # logs location set on each server
```